# How to fool the bridge to redirect packages of a IP not owned by any interface

Tags: iptables, firewall, nat, iptables-redirect

I want to redirect the traffic between interfaces over a virtual bridge, when a specific match of IP and port pass through.

For instance, when I connect to `10.20.30.40` on port `2222` inside a guest over a virtual `tun` interface which pass through the virtual bridge to my physical interface I want to intercept that traffic and redirect it to `127.0.0.1` on port `3333` on the host instead of going to internet, it seems easy, first open the server on the host:

```
nc -vkl 127.0.0.1 3333
```

Now apply the `iptables` rule on the host:

```
sudo iptables \
  -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp \
  -d 10.20.30.40 --dport 2222 \
  -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3333
```

Now to test you can run on the host:

```
nc -vzw5 10.20.30.40 2222
```

Nice, it seems to work locally on the host, but here is the problem when running on a guest:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.9 nc -vzw5 10.20.30.40 2222
```

The thing is `docker` creates a virtual bridge, so the traffic is not local on the host any more, in my researches I found some rules I could apply on the host:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp \
  -d 10.20.30.40 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3333
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp \
  -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 3333 -j SNAT --to-source 10.20.30.40:2222
```

But it didn't work... How could I make the traffic going through the `docker0` bridge to be redirected to `lo` interface on the host when match the specific rules?

Some premises:

- The target IP does not belong to any interface subnet;
- The solution cannot involve using DNS neither change hosts on `docker` or `/etc/hosts`;
- The `iptables` rules should be applied on the host only;
- The server must be assigned to the local machine, the traffic cannot leak into the network, in that case, it cannot be direct accessible by any guest via the host IP on port `3333`, neither be accessible by any external machine via the physical interface;

Comment: Options: (1) don't use a bridge, (2) turn your bridge into a [brouter](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html). A bridge works on layer 2, you want rules on layer 3. This two things don't go together.

Comment: @dirkt traffic targeted to internet inside the bridge is being routed to the interface which is connected to internet as expected, what I want is to intercept a specific match of IP and port and redirect to other server.

Comment: Either you have several interface connected to a single bridge, one which connects to the internet. Then it's layer 2, and see my comment above. Or, the interface connected to the internet is **not** connected to the bridge, and then it won't work. If the "bridge" is actually part of Docker, and not a bridge you made, then I wouldn't mess with iptables at all, because Docker uses all kinds of iptables rules, and you'll break things. Instead, use a proper Docker configuration (which means you should describe what exactly you want to achieve wrt to your containers). Please update the question.

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer, but there is little I can add, only that the bridge is a virtual interface, but if you follow the instructions I gave in commands it is expected you to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dirkt do you think it is not possible to intercept a traffic that is forwarded by the host from a guest to internet via iptables?

Comment: I think it's not *advisable* to try to mess with the Docker iptables, assuming this is what your actual problem is. Even though the Docker documentation talks about networks with a "bridge" driver, and there's a Linux kernel bridge involved, it's not a simple bridge, there's lost of iptables rules on top of that (have a look at them and see yourself). Yes, you can probably figure out which chain to use in this setup to do your intercept, but it'll break when you update Docker to a version where they decided to change their setup.

Comment: The *clean* way is to either do whatever you want in Docker using a suitable Docker setup, possibly modifying your containers a bit, or maybe throwing in extra DNS. But for that you need to describe what you actually want to achieve (see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), here your Y is "I think it's a good idea to put tun interfaces and redirects to localhost on a Docker host and expect this to solve my problem". Your Y maybe can be made to work, but not without understanding the complete Docker setup.

Comment: @dirkt unfortunately the problem is that I am testing a playbook that setup a huge set of containers, and some of them require connection of services from a private network that I cannot achieve directly from my local machine, as I do not want to create conditional recipes, since it have to be the same as the production environment, I opted to create a ssh tunnel in order to test it, but them I cannot spoil the docker settings in order to make it connectible, but I can interfere in my local machine to forward the traffic as I wish, that is the solution I had thought.

Comment: It would have been helpful if this information was included in the question. The quickest way I can think of to make this work is to add another layer that's free or mostly free of the Docker's iptables rules, and mock the production environment in that layer: E.g. run Docker in a VM, and tweak egress from the VM on the VM host. The alternative is to work through all the Docker iptables rules, find out how they work, and find out how to insert your redirection into this. Not something I'd like to do myself.